# Duplicate transactions in blockchain

Tags: blockchain, wallet, transaction-id

Can someone explain what does this mean:
[image: Problem]
As i see: 2 transactions are having SAME txid and differ just by address. Is this normal behavior? Should I get both transactions in such cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions can have multiple outputs. What you show are two outputs created by the [same transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/6b143842156ecb2355af576fcd98b3e177bd7467916e422b10597b971c9e7d0d).

The output positions are enumerated with the `vout` field. As the first one is `vout = 0`, the two that you show are the third and fourth output.

Comment: So its legit: i have 2 incomes?

Comment: @0x49D1: If both of those addresses belong to you, which is what seems to be the case, then you've received two UTXO with the balances of 0.0874 and 0.103 BTC.

Comment: Can one transaction have two of the same output address, maybe from different senders? Edit: Yes: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22295/how-can-there-be-multiple-outputs-with-same-address-in-the-same-transaction