# Cost of single vs multiple outputs to the same address

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, raw-transaction, coin-age-priority

A transaction [can have multiple outputs pointing to the same address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/can-a-single-transaction-have-multiple-outputs-going-to-the-same-address) however it's not clear to me if and how this affects the transaction's **`priority`** and **`cost`**?

As an example, let's consider these two simple cases:

- `Case A`: Two outputs pointing to the same address use the same input in a 50/50 split.
- `Case B`: Two outputs pointing to the same address use two different inputs of equal amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transaction that has multiple output scripts that point to the same address would be no different from a transaction in which every output script pointed to a different address. So when you have two outputs to the same transaction, all that matters is that you have 2 outputs and the size of those outputs (byte-wise).

[Transaction priority](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Technical_info) is calculated as follows:

`priority = sum(input_value_in_base_units * input_age)/size_in_bytes`

As you can see, only the tx size matters and the input value and age. None of these are influenced by the address to which coins are sent.

Comment: But the `cost` would be smaller if the two outputs in the question's example merge into a single output, right?

Comment: Well, yes. The cost is related to the priority. But for a 2-output tx, the cost will almost always be zero.